# How to graph by hand the growth rate of a program?

Tags: java, big-o

Below is a simple for loop. I understand using growth rate analysis to look at a program and determine its rate. However, my question is after a program runs and you actually see the speed of which it works, how would you graph the actual growth rate of the program?

```
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();


    int sum = 0;
    int N = 1000000;

    for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        sum += Math.sqrt(i);
    }

    long endTime = System.nanoTime();
    long duration = (endTime - startTime);

    System.out.println("Here is the time it takes "+ duration);
```

Comment: jfreechart could use to plot your results

Comment: axis x -> input length (N), axis y -> duration. I'd experiment with multiple lengths (from 0 to 10^5, step by 10000 maybe)

Answer (score 0):

Big O follows a certain trend depending on the complexity of the program.

[Types of Big O Explained](http://bigocheatsheet.com/)

[Big O explained](https://justin.abrah.ms/computer-science/big-o-notation-explained.html)

I have listed some resources that I think should be useful.

Also if you don't need to draw it by hand, try looking up some Java resources that generate graphs.